# CSS is not working with the Opera and Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, css, cross-browser

I've read other posts related to this but not get much for myself so I'm asking it here.

My `CSS` is working very well with the `IE8`, `Chrome` and `Safari` but doesn't work with the `Firefox` and `Opera`.

```
body 
{
    background:FFFFCC;

    font: bold 11px/1.5em Verdana;
    }

h1 {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

hr {
    border:none;
    border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height:1px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    }

#tabs {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#BBF5F6;
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:normal;
    }

#tabs ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
    list-style:none;
    }

#tabs li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#tabs a {
    float:left;
    background:url("space.gif") no-repeat left top;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

#tabs a span {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:url("complete.gif") no-repeat right top;
    padding:5px 5px 4px 6px;
    color:#FFF;
    }

/* Commented Backslash Hack hides rule from IE5-Mac \*/
#tabs a span {float:none;}

/* End IE5-Mac hack */
#tabs a:hover span {
    color:#FFF;
    }

#tabs a:hover {
    background-position:0% -42px;
    }

#tabs a:hover span {
    background-position:100% -42px;
    }
```

I'm using this with the `ASP.NET` for my project. Is there anything that I'm missing.

Css in Chrome
[image]

Css in FF

[image]

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Also, what HTML are you using with this? Even with your full CSS, I have no idea how this would (or should) look in any browser.

Comment: you should describe your problem here.

Comment: @Nightfirecat, sikender I added the screen shots what is exactly not working.

Comment: @avirk Is that your html http://jsfiddle.net/2JduM/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. OMG how stupid I'm  was using just `\` for instead of `/` for link the `css` to my page. And this was working with others browsers without any problem and making trouble on `Opera` and `FireFox`.  Sorry guys for this stupid one.

Answer (score 0):

```
background:#FFFFCC;

#tabs a span { *float:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body 
{
    background:FFFFCC;
    font: bold 11px/1.5em Verdana;
}
```

1. You should use **background-color** instead of **background**.
2. Color code must be start with ***#*** so change your code from ***FFFFCC*** to ***#FFFFCC***.

Comment: background is a valid shortcut property. You are right about the hash mark, though.